# Network analysis (service area) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, service-area, accessibility

Through network analysis/service area analysis ex) While walking a certain distance through a pedestrian path, I would like to find the service coverage area of pedestrian A and pedestrian B with different walking speeds.

I am proceeding with two methods, but with both methods it is difficult to derive the desired value, so I am asking a question.

First, I set the length as a Impedance value and a Walking time of A and B to the Time cost. Then, when running network analysis, the desired distance (ex) 250m, 500m was set as the Cut off value.But the result is derived only for the value set in Cut off, regardless of the walking time set in Time cost, the area value is same.(Cut off 250m/500m)

To complement this, I set the walking time to an impedance value and put a value corresponding to the length in Distance cost. Then I set the Cut off value based on the same time of 10 minutes. The result was different between Speed_A value and Speed_B. But a problem is the area made over distance or short distance. To cover this, before analyzing i set a search tolerance(250m/500m). Even though, the area result just derived by cut off value(Time cost). I do not know that is method is right to do.

After using the above two methods, I would like to find the area up to a certain distance regarding pedestrian's different walking times(speeds).

Do you know the method or could you tell me what is wrong in the process?